# PHP - while (!feof()) doesn't handle the last line

Tags: php, while-loop

My code doesn't read the last line, do you know why? All lines are handled except the last one in my CSV file

```
$cpt = 0;

$fp = fopen("$file", "r");

while (!feof($fp))
{
    $cpt++;
    if($cpt == 1) // First line
    {
        $line = fgets($fp,4096);
        $data = explode( ";",$line);
    }

    if($data[0] != "") // Last line
    {
        // Insert DB
        $line = fgets($fp3,4096); // Next line
        $data = explode( ";",$ligne3);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you determine that? The given code does not read **any** line of the file

Comment: The _proper_ way to read CSV data from a file in PHP is `fgetcsv`. The manual has an easy example on how to use it, and `feof` is not even involved.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, you are right, I forgot to put some of the code, sorry



`$cpt = 0;

$fp = fopen("$file", "r");

while (!feof($fp))
{
 $cpt++;
 if($cpt == 1) // First line
 {
  $line = fgets($fp,4096);
  $data = explode( ";",$line);
 }

 if($data[0] != "") // Last line
 {
  // Insert DB
  $line = fgets($fp3,4096); // Next line
  $data = explode( ";",$ligne3);
 }
}`

Comment: @CBroe thx, i'll check

Comment: Please add all code to your question by editing it

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It is my while that is the problem. I have displayed in different places echo in the while and an echo at the end of my while and my last line is read after my while when it should be read in my while

Comment: I tried like this and same result, my last line is read after my while

```$cpt = 0;

$fp = fopen("$file", "r");

$line = fgets($fp,4096);
$data = explode( ";",$line);

while (!feof($fp))
{
    $cpt++;
    
    // Insert DB
    $line = fgets($fp3,4096); // Next line
    $data = explode( ";",$ligne3);
}```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgetcsv` to read CSV-file. The example below reads one line of a CSV-file at a time, in an exploded format directly into the `$data`-array.

```
$fp = fopen("$file", "r");

while(!feof($fp)) {
    
    //Reads the current line of CSV-file into $data
    $data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ";");
    
}
```

Read more about `fgetcsv` here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp

Comment: Thx, I don't know this function, I'll have a look but I have to rework all my CSV handling